# URL rewriting only in main domain

Tags: nginx, rules

I am trying to use a package to optimize my main site and when I follow the [instructions](https://github.com/JosephSilber/page-cache#url-rewriting) it works great but it messes up all subdomains as well. Can I somehow exclude any subdomain from this location lookup ?

The change I need to make is this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /page-cache/$uri.html /page-cache/$uri.json /page-cache/$uri.xml /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

But I need this to be applied only to the main domain, any other subdomain should use this one

```
 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can split your server block in two, the first one for the main domain and the second one for the subdomains.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Can I use a wildcard character?

Comment: Yes, something like `server_name domain.com` (or `server_name domain.com www.domain.com`) for the first server block and `server_name *.domain.com` for the second one. [Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) are the docs.

Comment: Please add your full nginx configuration given by `nginx -T` to your question.

Comment: more details needed